# Stretchability/shrinkability of \phantom and \llap and \rlap?

Tags: tex-core, boxes, glue

if a `\hbox{...}` contains some glue, e.g., due to space-tokens, the width of that `\hbox{...}` can spread or shrink.

Do `\phantom` and `\llap` and `\rlap` spread/shrink in the same way?

In terms of code-snippets:

Does something like

```
\hbox{content of horizontal box}
```

in the resulting output-file (.dvi/.pdf) always yield exactly the same look as

```
\hbox{\phantom{content of horizontal box}\llap{content of horizontal box}}
```

or as

```
\hbox{\rlap{content of horizontal box}\phantom{content of horizontal box}}
```

?

(If so, I could use this for adding pdf-specials in the right places...)

Answer (score 2):

Jewdokija, you say:

> if a \hbox{...} contains some glue, e.g., due to space-tokens, the
>   width of that \hbox{...} can spread or shrink.

Are you sure?    ;-)

Regarding `\hbox`, `\phantom`, `\llap` and `\rlap` and stretchability/shrinkability:

Be aware that `\hbox`, `\phantom`, `\llap` and `\rlap` process their argument in **restricted** horizontal mode.

Quote from a dangerous-bend paragraph in "Chapter 12: Glue" of the TeXbook:

> In the simplest case, when you just want a box to have **its natural width**, you don’t have to write
>   `\hbox spread 0pt`; you can simply say `\hbox{⟨contents of box⟩}`.

As you can see both with the statement quoted above and with the example shown below, stretchability/shrinkability of glue is not necessarily the same in (non-restricted) horizontal mode as in **restricted** horizontal mode. ;-)

To put it simply:

(Non-restricted) horizontal mode is the mode where TeX will break a paragraph into lines of specifiied length for you and hereby calculate glue for things to fit nicely into lines of specified length.
Restricted horizontal mode is the mode where no line-breaking occurs at all as everything is assumed to belong to the same line of text, no matter how long that line might be.

```
\noindent Here ``content of horizontal box'' is processed while in horizontal mode:\hfill\break

\noindent content of horizontal box\break

\noindent Here ``content of horizontal box'' is  processed while in restricted horizontal mode:\hfill\break

\noindent\phantom{content of horizontal box}\llap{content of horizontal box}\break

\noindent\rlap{content of horizontal box}\phantom{content of horizontal box}\break

\noindent\hbox{content of horizontal box}\break

\noindent\hbox{\phantom{content of horizontal box}\llap{content of horizontal box}}\break

\noindent\hbox{\rlap{content of horizontal box}\phantom{content of horizontal box}}\break

\bye
```

[image]